# Time-dependent coloring in C#

Tags: c#, time, comparison

I need time-dependent coloring in a project. If the system is 10 minutes past the entrance time, the background will be orange. If it is 20 minutes past it will be red. I found the difference between the two dates using the

```
DateTime.Parse(timeNow).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(timeLogged));
```

but I can't compare the result.

```
if(Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Parse(timeNow).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(timeLogged)))>10)
```

Does it have a similar use? Can you help me how to do it?

I am using Google Translate because my English is not very good, and I apologize for the language mistakes I made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subtract `DateTime` objects. You'll get a `TimeSpan`. You can use that `TimeSpan` to determine the difference between the original objects:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Parse(timeNow);
DateTime logged = DateTime.Parse(timeLogged);
TimeSpan diff = now - logged;
if (diff.TotalMinutes > 10)
    // It's been more than 10 minutes.
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Subtract returns a Timespan object that has a TotalMinutes property, so you could do this:

```
if (DateTime.Parse(timeNow).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(timeLogged)).TotalMinutes > 10)
```

Comment: if you have 65 minutes diff it will show 5 minutes as minutes ( and 1 as hours)..

Answer (score 0):

You could do this aswell

```
// If older than 20 min
if(DateTime.Parse(timeLogged) < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: You need to take DST into account.

Comment: @itsme86 sorry I don't really get your comment? What do you mean with DST?

Comment: Daylight Savings Time. If you're in a region that has DST, the time changes twice a year. `DateTime.Now` might suddenly be 2:00AM after 2:59AM, which would give incorrect results. `DateTime.UtcNow` is one way to avoid this problem.